# PorterStemmer Stemmer Not Stemming Words Unless At End of String (in Python)

Tags: python, nlp, porter-stemmer

I am creating a bot that talks about chess, and right now I am preprocessing. The problem is, when the Python program stems the words in the string, it will not do anything unless the word is the final word. That is the output. What I expected is for the stemmer to stem every word in the sentence that the user types in. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
import re
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
port = PorterStemmer()

print("Hello! I am the ChessBot. I will talk about chess, but can only talk     about chess. Nothing else. I can't even understand a greeting! Now, initiate this conversation!")

while True:
    userinput = input('> ')
    userinput = re.sub('(\?|\.|!|,)', '', userinput)
    userinput = str.lower(userinput)
    userinput = userinput.split('\s')
    userinput = " ".join([port.stem(word) for word in userinput])
    print(userinput)
```

Comment: `str.split` doesn't use regex syntax so `\s` won't work as you expect, try `userinput.split()` to split on general whitespace.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem... even though it wasn't an answer.